# latex does not open after sleep mode my imac from 2020

Tags: texshop

I have an imac 3.3ghz intel core i5 6 kernels 8ghz of memory, AMD Radeon Pro 5300 4 GB, with macos monterey 12.2

I have texshop. In the folder /usr/local/texlive i have the three folders 2019, 2019 basic and texmf-local.

I run tex. When I finish, I switch off the computer, but sometimes I do not exit from tex. Then, next day when I try to open it again, it keeps trying, as in the picture, but never starts.

[image: tex trying]

Comment: This sounds like an issue specifically with your editor, either a bug or unexpected behaviour from shut down forcing the editor closed. If you can, try updating TeXShop, or confirming you have a recent version.  How reliably can you reproduce this issue? Does it occur for any file or only some? Is it dependent on having compiled the source or done something else specific in TeX? Probably the best course of action is to attempt to report a bug https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/bugreports.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get 100% effectiveness. Each time i shut down the computer with tex open, it makes the same reaction afterwards. It happens with any file. And I have tried after compiling and before, with tex in the front page and somewhere hidden on the screen below something. I will report.

Comment: all useful information to include in a bug report, if updating or reinstalling doesn't resolve things then the best bet is to get in touch with the developers.

Comment: I wrote to Richard, and he had a precise solution to the problem, by no restarting tex authomatically. Thanks Dai.